# FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: mistakenly called

Tags: facebook, caching, uinavigationcontroller, facebook-ios-sdk

I am caching the login token locally, however I have a navigation view in place and when I'm logged in, if I pop the "facebook" view controller, then push it, and do that once again, FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: is returned (as well as FBSessionStateOpen immediately before) on the second push of the view... Any thoughts as to why this is happening?
Thanks